# Можно ли дополнять файл лицензий APL 2.0 и MIT переводами оригинального текста на другие языки?

Tags: лицензирование, интернационализация

Вопрос в заголовке. Если внизу оригинального текста на английском я припишу переводы лицензии на некоторые европейские и азиатские языки, не потеряет ли он своей юридической силы? Отдельные файлы с переводами тоже есть, они находятся в каталогах `/i18n/LANG`, где `LANG` – самоназвание языка, но интересует именно возможность интернационализации файла `LICENSE` в корневом каталоге.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод должен быть официально одобрен авторами оригинального текста лицензии, в противном случае, он не имеет юридической силы.

Размещение в одном файле оригинального текста лицензии и перевода фактически, является модификацией этого самого файла (лицензии), которая также должна быть одобрена авторами оригинала - *они по-русски не понимают*, вдруг вы написали дисклеймер так, что это и не дисклеймер вовсе.

**Коротко**, лицензия в опенсорсе, это, пожалуй, единственный файл, который нельзя модифицировать свободно.

Comment: А если написать disclaimer что перевод не имеет юр силы, только оригинал?

Comment: Могут притянуть за уши тезис о том, что допускается смешение официального текста и неофициального, поэтому, формулировка дисклеймера, в таком случае тоже должна быть одобрена авторами оригинала.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую получить одобрение Apache на один из найденных русских переводов APL 2.0, где терминология приведена под российское делопроизводство, но у меня два вопроса. Насколько важен вид используемых кавычек в правовом документе, чтобы он имел юрсилу на территории РФ (в переводе используются "ёлочки")? И подойдёт ли для этого кодировка документа UTF-8, или обязательно должен быть ГОСТ?

Comment: @arelive - это уже оффтопик, задавайте отдельные вопросы.